# Permutation and Combination (Different way on calculating the total combination)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here are two questions with different methods on calculating the total number of combinations:

[image: 2 question with different method on calculating the total combination]

Can anyone please help to explain why the way they calculating the total number of selection on part (c) is so much different as compare in part (d)? On part (c), they consider the way to choose the O and R, but in part (d) they did not include the way to choose the E and R.

It should be only total of 10 ways for part (c) if we follows the method on part (d), which is
ORTM
ORTW
ORMW
OORT
OORM
OORW
ORRT
ORRM
ORRW
OORR

The only different I observed here is (c) is looking for probability but (d) is not. But I am still not convinced by this reason. Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: For the probability question, under most reasonable interpretations of the problem of how to randomize what selection you get you will have that the multiple copies of the same letter are still treated as distinct for the purposes of pulling letters randomly in a fair way.  For the second problem, yes it is not asking for a probability and instead a count.  Whether you *choose* to treat the letters as distinct or equivalent if they were the same letter is a *choice*.  The author treated them as the same, hence the difference.

Comment: Remember a few things... probability being $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ is only going to be guaranteed if outcomes are equally likely.  The counting used by the author in part (d) are **not** equally likely to occur.  It can still be a valid way to answer the question of how to count there, depending on what you do or don't consider "different."  The scenario for part (c) was that we chose to consider them different so as to help make it so that outcomes *are* equally likely so we can use counting techniques to find probabilities.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your quick and thorough response. So I guess the rule of thumb is that whenever we talk about probability, then we have to treat the same letter as distinct input and thus the way to choose the letter from the given condition is important. When we talking about the possible selection, by assumption we should treat the same letter as identical and hence the way to choose the letter from the given condition is not included to calculate the total possible selection. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: For a "rule of thumb" it is fine, but keep an open eye out for when that rule needs to be broken.  Also keep an eye for when order needs to matter.  Scenarios like (c) above you could have treated it either way as order mattering or not so long as you are consistent with your choice and you would arrive at the same final answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz Alright, highly appreciate for your input!